# kotlin, coroutines, NoSuchMethodError when calling overriden suspended function from other module

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

Whenever I try to execute overrided suspend method which is defined in other module it fails with `NoSuchMethodError` (see more details below).

Here what I am doing exactly:

I have two modules **app** and **lib**.

**lib** here I have an interface (`OtherModuleInterface`) with suspend method (`test`).

**app** here I have defined implementation (`OtherModuleImpl`) of that interface.

If I call it like this:

```
 val myOtherModuleObject : OtherModuleImpl = OtherModuleImpl()
    runBlocking { myOtherModuleObject.test() }
```

Then it works fine.

If I use `OtherModuleInterface` as type of value:

```
val myOtherModuleObject : OtherModuleInterface = OtherModuleImpl()
runBlocking { myOtherModuleObject.test() }
```

It fails with exception:

> **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.lib.OtherModuleInterface.test(Lkotlin/coroutines/experimental/Continuation;)Ljava/lang/Object**.

If I put both interface and implementation in the same module it works fine:

```
val mySameModuleObject : SameModuleInterface = SameModuleImpl()
    runBlocking { mySameModuleObject.test() }
```

You can check out code here to see whole project configuration:
https://github.com/rjuszczyk/kotlin-coroutines-problem
and run `ExampleUnitTest` to see the error.

Comment: Have you tried adding  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8" statement under lib gradle? It should look like this                                               dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
}

Comment: @lib4 I found that adding `implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:0.25.0'` to ***lib*** module also solves problem. I have checked with gradlew app:dependencies what those two dependencies have in common and it turned out that it is: `implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.61'` lib and adding this one to ***lib*** module is sufficient to fix the problem. Thank you!

Comment: you can see the commit which fixed the problem here:
https://github.com/rjuszczyk/kotlin-coroutines-problem/commit/30d81a1a2406c1bc2d2677b31f423fb9443b3611