# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method getTopRatedMoviesAsync()Lkotlinx/coroutines/Deferred;

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm getting this error when trying to run my app that uses an Android Module to load a list of objects from the Web:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method getTopRatedMoviesAsync()Lkotlinx/coroutines/Deferred; in class Lcom/example/topratedmovies/network/TmdbApi; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.example.topratedmovies.network.TmdbApi' appears in /data/app/com.example.mynetflixclone-mj27Djaz9ecQx8TopvKI0A==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk)
        at com.example.topratedmovies.viewmodel.TopRatedMoviesViewModel$fetchAllTrending$1.invokeSuspend(TopRatedMoviesViewModel.kt:17)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:238)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2019-08-20 09:42:16.280 1607-1607/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/29688/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-08-20 09:42:16.335 1884-1958/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '48df775 com.example.mynetflixclone/com.example.mynetflixclone.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2019-08-20 09:42:19.086 1736-1821/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2019-08-20 09:42:19.540 1884-2011/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
2019-08-20 09:42:23.866 1884-1898/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-08-20 09:42:23.870 1884-1898/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
```

**I've tried the solution in this two links:**

[kotlin, coroutines, NoSuchMethodError when calling overriden suspended function from other module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52037520/kotlin-coroutines-nosuchmethoderror-when-calling-overriden-suspended-function)

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/775

**But didn't work.**

I tried to fix this by inserting this line in my android module:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.61'
```

and then:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.2.2'
```

and then:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
```

each line at a time. Nothing worked.

**This is the method that contains the line pointed in the logcat:**

```
fun fetchAllTrending(){
        Log.d("trendingtitle", "fetchAllTrending() called")
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val trendings = Apifactory.tmdbApi.getTopRatedMoviesAsync() <--LINE POINTED BY LOGCAT
            try {
                var result = trendings.await()
                trendingsLiveData.value = result.results

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                trendingsLiveData.value = ArrayList<TopRatedMovies>()
            }
        }
    }
```

**The `getTopRatedMoviesAsync` method:**

```
import com.example.topratedmovies.model.TopRatedMoviesResponse
import kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface TmdbApi{
    @GET("movie/top_rated")
    fun getTopRatedMoviesAsync() : Deferred<TopRatedMoviesResponse>
}
```

**`Build.gradle` Project level:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**`build.gradle` file of the module:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.0.0'

    //To solve NoSuchMethod Error
//    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.61'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.2.2'
//    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'


    def moshiVersion="1.8.0"
    def retrofit2_version = "2.5.0"
    def okhttp3_version = "3.12.0"
    def kotlinCoroutineVersion = "1.0.1"
    def picassoVersion = "2.71828"

    //ViewModel Scope
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01'

    //TODO Test app on an amulator with API 28
    //recyclerview
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

    //Moshi
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$moshiVersion"
    kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:$moshiVersion"

    //Retrofit2
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit2_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$retrofit2_version"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:0.9.2"
    //Because of an error with JAR version
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:'1.3.31'"

    //Okhttp3
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp3_version"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'

    //Picasso
    implementation ("com.squareup.picasso:picasso:$picassoVersion"){
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }

    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if your retrofit implementation is adding the `CoroutineCallAdapterFactory` like the example below.

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://example.com/")
    .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory()) // <- Check this line
    .build()
```

---

Another way to use coroutines with Retrofit is by upgrading it to `2.6.+`. In this version, the coroutines are supported by default, and then you can remove the `retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter` library.

Comment: Yes, I was using `CoroutineCallAdapterFactory`. Even so, I removed it and upgraded Retrofit to `2.6.2`, but nothing chaged. I'm getting the same error. Seems that `Deferred` can not be found in the libraries.

Comment: Try to also add android coroutines library (`org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.2.2`). Also, check the proguard/R8. If it's on, maybe you should add some rules to the configuration file. https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/jvm/resources/META-INF/proguard/coroutines.pro

Comment: I just created another project, now in Android Studio 3.5, imported the same modules and it's working.

Comment: The same error is being displayed on logcat again! I just added coroutines as dependency (`org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.2.2`), but it didn't work. About proguard. I did nothing with it. It's just AS default.